# preview_post_link for Custom Post Types

Tags: filters, previews

I've got a custom post type, and I'd like to be able to change the preview link but from what I can tell, the hook for preview_post_link only affects the default post type.

Any guidance?

Here's what I've been trying.

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'append_preview_query_vars' );

function append_preview_query_vars( $link, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type === "2016program" ) {
        return $link . "?program_year=2016";
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two problems here:

**#1**

You're missing the `$accepted_args` argument in:

```
add_filter( $tag, $callback_function, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

Check out the [Codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters) for more info on that.

**#2**

Note that `$link . "?program_year=2016"` is problematic, since it gives us this kind of link:

```
 /?p=123&preview=true?program_year=2016
```

But using instead `add_query_arg( [ 'program_year' => '2016' ], $link )` we get the correct form:

```
/?p=123&preview=true&program_year=2016
```

### Updated code snippet:

Please try this instead (PHP 5.4+):

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', function ( $link, \WP_Post $post )
{
    return '2016program' === $post->post_type 
        ? add_query_arg( [ 'program_year' => '2016' ], $link ) 
        : $link;

 }, 10, 2 ); // Notice the number of arguments is 2 for $link and $post
```

where we use `add_query_arg()` to append the extra GET parameter to the link.

Comment: This is great. Thanks a ton. I'm noticing that this doesn't seem to affect the "Preview Changes" button on the edit post page, but only the preview link on the index.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the filter isn't applied to the *Preview Changes* link for *published* posts. You will have to use the `post_link` filter, with some restrictions, for that one. As soon as you change the post status to something else than `publish`, the filter will work on the *Preview* link.  @andrewheins

Answer (score 0):

Trying @birgire's solution. Is it valid for Wordpress 4.x?

I can't add any fot eh preview_post_link or preview_page_link filters. The function jsut doesn't get hit.

```
function bitflower_change_post_link($link, $post) {

        //replace www part with server1 using the following php function
        //preg_replace ( patter, replace, subject ) syntax
        // $link = preg_replace('/cms/', '', $link);
        $link = $link . '?testttttt=1';
        return $link;
}
add_filter('preview_post_link', 'bitflower_change_post_link', 10, 2);
```

I've tried with the 10,2 parameters and without. I've had a string written to a file to see if the filter gets hit. No luck.

The official code reference of Wordpress does list at least the filter preview_post_link.

Any ideas?

PS: wanted to comment but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question, I think a new one would be more appropriate? ;-) If the status of the post is *publish*, then this filter will not be activated.